# Woocommerce subscriptions: Updating order meta data from subscription meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, crud, woocommerce-subscriptions

I've written the following code to take Stripe payment details from a Woocommerce subscription and update the related order with those details.

It's grabbing the details fine but the `update_post_meta` code doesn't seem to fire and just leaves those fields blank in the post meta, what am I missing? The rest of the code works as intended.

```
$order_id = wc_get_order( '143025' );
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ));

foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription_obj ){
   $current_subs_id = $subscription_obj->get_id(); // This is current subscription id

     $stripe_cus = get_post_meta( $current_subs_id, '_stripe_customer_id' );
     $stripe_cus = $stripe_cus[0];

     $stripe_src = get_post_meta( $current_subs_id, '_stripe_source_id' );
     $stripe_src = $stripe_src[0];

     update_post_meta( $order_id, '_stripe_customer_id', $stripe_cus );
     update_post_meta( $order_id, '_stripe_source_id', $stripe_src );

}
```

The two strings look like `cus_Hjgys757` and `src_1nHyyin75` for `$stripe_cus` and `$stripe_src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you make a confuncion between order object and order ID in your code. Also you could try using CRUD methods instead like:

```
$order_id      = 143025;
$order         = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Order Object
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) ); // Array of subscriptions Objects

foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
     $stripe_cust_id = $subscription->get_meta( '_stripe_customer_id');
     $stripe_src_id  = $subscription->get_meta( '_stripe_source_id' );

     $order->update_meta_data( '_stripe_customer_id', $stripe_cust_id );
     $order->update_meta_data( '_stripe_source_id', $stripe_src_id );
     $order->save();
}
```

Or the old way using WordPress `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()` functions:

```
$order_id      = 143025;
$order         = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Order Object
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) ); // Array of subscriptions Objects

foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
     $stripe_cust_id = get_post_meta( $subscription_id, '_stripe_customer_id', true );
     $stripe_src_id  = get_post_meta( $subscription_id, '_stripe_source_id', true );

     update_post_meta( $order_id, '_stripe_customer_id', $stripe_cust_id );
     update_post_meta( $order_id, '_stripe_source_id', $stripe_src_id );
}
```

Both should work.

Comment: Ahhhh so close, thanks for clearing that up. I'll just put this in a pending-payment trigger and it should retry a renewal with the newly updated card details instead of just retrying old card details constantly.